# Safe rated pressure for a sankey connection

Tags: keg, pressure

Does anyone know the rated pressure for a Sankey connector? I see Sankey-fitting kegs are rated 60-120 PSI, so is it safe to assume the connectors themselves are good for at least 60psi? (I'm making sparkling wines so 60PSI is about what I need)

Answer (score 1):

Well the weakest point will always be the polymer based tubing used to carry the wine.  So the ratings on the fittings are moot I'd suspect.  Go with the highest rated food grade tubing and the fittings will still out rate the tubing.

Answer (score 0):

The only sure way to know are:

1. Ask the manufacturer
2. Visit certification station. Or whatever is the proper name, the point where divers go to have their gear certified when previous certificate is no longer valid. They might be able to test for you.
3. Buy fittings with pressure ratings documented. Probably cheaper than option 2.